# Iterate over columns and rows in a pandas dataframe and convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, rows

I have the following dataframe:

```
col1  col2  col3
25,4  34,2  33,2
33,25 30.2  10,2
.................
```

and I want to iterate all over the columns and rows from this dataset.

```
df_range = len(df)

for column in df:
  for i in range(df_range):
    str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
    print(df)
```

and I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-38-47f6c96d2e67> in <module>()
      3 for column in df2:
      4   for i in range(df_range):
----> 5     str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
      6 
      7     print(df)

TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would `str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)` give you anything useful? There's nothing in that expression that involves the thing you're iterating over. Even if it were to evaluate to something without an error, it would evaluate to the same thing in each iteration of the loop.

If you do `df.loc[i,column].replace(',','.')`, then `replace` is a method from the string object `df.loc[i,column]`, and takes two arguments `old` and `new`. However, when you do `str.replace(',','.')`, `replace` is a method from the `str` *type*, not from a string *instance*, and so requires the arguments `self` `old` and `new`. The first argument `','` gets interpreted as `self`, and that leaves `'.'` as `old` and nothing for `new`. When you use `replace`, you have to either give it the original string as an argument, or take the `replace` method from the original string.

Also, you shouldn't be iterating through `df` with indices. Us `applymap` instead.